# How to add Middleware in Azure HttpTrigger Functions (in-process function app) (Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions) in .net

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, .net-6.0

I found one sample on Stackoverflow ([How to insert a middleware in Azure Durable Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75236328/how-to-insert-a-middleware-in-azure-durable-functions)), but it also just talks about Isolated and Duarable Trigger functions. I want to add middlelayer in Azure HttpTrigger (Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions) Functions in .net

I am creating a project in .Net 6. This project will have HttpTrigger type of Azure functions.

When I created the default project from Visual Studio Azure function template, it has just created a simple function file and project without startup and Program.cs.

I can define other layers like data layer, business layer, etc. but the problem I am facing is:

How to add Middleware layer in Azure Functions (Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions) application?

One solution I feel might be we can add a program.cs file to the project which will have a main method? My doubt is can we add Program.cs file to this project, what could be the implications?

Or is their a way to use Startup.cs to configure middlewares?

Why this doubt of adding Program.cs file came to my mind is because, all the online examples I am seeing is for Isolated Azure Function. and their is no reference of HttpTrigger function, so is it correct to add a program.cs to HttpTrigger function project.

I have already added Startup.cs for dependency Injection.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure Functions application must use the isolated process, in which case you use the `HostBulder.AddMiddleware<T>` method to add middleware when configuring the function worker:

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults( builder =>
    {
        builder.AddApplicationInsights()
            .AddApplicationInsightsLogger()

            .UseMiddleware<YourMiddleweare>()
    } )
    .ConfigureServices( services =>
    {
        ... add services to DI container here ...
    }
    .Build();
```

Comment: So, should I change my normal httptrigger functions to isolatedtrigger functions? Also you mean, we shouldn’t add a Program.cs to normal httptrigger functions application

Comment: It's the hosting model, has nothing to do with the type of trigger for the function; ie: it's global for the Functions application, not specific to functions.  The isolated hosting is the future whereas the in-process is legacy.  The durable functionality was previously only available in-process but it seems that's changed and is now available for isolated process function applications.  As such, I'd suggest all your greenfield function applications use the isolated hosting model.

Comment: Understood thanks, I also did some research and came to the same conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

**Adding important discussions and my findings and some links around in-process function app.**

- If you have this: `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` as dependency in your solution you have in-process function app. If you are in .Net6, and you create a Function App solution in Visual Studio, it will create in-process function app, with no Startup or Program file. These functions you can directly copy paste to Azure Portal and run.
- but in-process function apps is legacy now. and it has support till .net6. After .net6, in-process function apps will be deprecated.
- .net6 is LTS release and in November 2023, we will have .Net8 release after which in-process function apps will be deprecated and we will just have isolated function apps. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-in-process-differences)
  [image]

**Conclusion:**

- Create Function Apps which are isolated function apps. You will not be able to edit directly in the Azure portal, but that is also just for learning and training. Real applications don't work from portals, you need a proper solution, proper dependency injection, middlewares, etc. Isolated function apps are the future.